# Input width based on available width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div that contains two more divs. The first inner div contains text which should not have a defined width. The second inner div contains an input field. Is it possible to make the second div (containing the input) span from the end of the first div (contains text) to the end of the container like so:

[image]

These are the classes that I intend to use:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="text">Text</div>
    <div class="input">
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 500px;
}

.text {
    float: left;
    width: auto;
}

.input {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.input input {
    width: 100%;
}
```

I did put some colors in that demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4zzzvrdd/

Comment: Too bad about the `width: auto`, great answer otherwise. ;-)